# How can Pandas read_csv() be forced not to stack rows with identical datatypes into an array?

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I've converted a larger csv file to HDF5 format using Pandas read_csv().
When loading it back in for in-kernel queries using PyTables, I see the data structure has changed from a string and 4 float fields to

```
"index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
"values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(4,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
"DateTime": StringCol(itemsize=34, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=2)
```

The csv file has been loaded into HDF5 using:

```
with pd.HDFStore(h5path, mode='w', complib='zlib', complevel=1) as store:
    reader = pd.read_csv(csvpath,
            chunksize=chunksize,
            header=None,
            skip_blank_lines=True,
            error_bad_lines=False,
            index_col=None,
            names=['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'AX', 'BX'])

    for chunk in reader:
        store.append('Quads', chunk, min_itemsize={'DateTime': 34}, expectedrows=6e7)
```

Loading the data in PyTables for furter processing goes as follows:

```
with pt.open_file(src_file, mode='r') as src:
    table = src.root.Quads.table
```

From here, the `table` i get has now been altered as described above.

A side effect of this bunching up are that the array no longer follows the order of the `names=[]` list, but are now alphabetically sorted.
Both args `names` and `index_col` indicate user controlled field ordering in the docs.

`Table.where()` clauses in PyTables does not work with multidimentional fields, which is why I'd like each field to stay seperate.

Per request, the csv file is organized as follows:

```
2015.01.01 22:01:31.779,1.21039,1.21062,0.75,0.75
2015.01.01 22:01:36.504,1.21041,1.21062,0.75,0.75
2015.01.01 22:01:36.581,1.21041,1.21064,1.50,1.50
2015.01.01 22:01:55.232,1.2105,1.21064,0.10,1.50
2015.01.01 22:01:56.927,1.2105,1.21063,0.10,0.75
```

Reading the resulting Pandas HDF5 file in HDFView 2.11 from the good boys at The HDF Group, shows the bunching happens in the Pandas created file and not in how PyTables reads the data. Heres HDFViews property output of the H5 file:

```
table (3096, 2)
Compound/Vdata,    17918341
Number of attributes = 17
    CLASS = TABLE
    DateTime_dtype = bytes272
    DateTime_kind = (lp0
VDateTime
p1
a.
    DateTime_meta = N.
    FIELD_0_FILL = 0
    FIELD_0_NAME = index
    FIELD_1_FILL = 0.0
    FIELD_1_NAME = values_block_0
    FIELD_2_FILL = 
    FIELD_2_NAME = DateTime
    NROWS = 17918341
    TITLE = 
    VERSION = 2.7
    index_kind = integer
    values_block_0_dtype = float64
    values_block_0_kind = (lp0
VA
p1
aVAX
p2
aVB
p3
aVBX
p4
a.
    values_block_0_meta = N.
```

Notice how the `values_block_0` occurs in the Pandas output but has not been added as a name in `read_csv()`

Comment: I'd guess whatever is happening is b/c of how the CSV is set up.  Can you show 3 or 4 lines of the CSV?

Comment: Sure. The original question has been updated with a bit of the csv file.

Comment: I loaded the example data into pandas with no problem. Can you show how you load it into HDF5 and back into the kernel? That may be where things go wrong...

Comment: Full read/write code has been updated. Btw, the reason why the DateTime field is being set as a 34 char string is, that there's some errors in the data further down the csv file that has to be cleaned out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, i ran the code without the zlib compression and the same `values_block_0` appear with the 4 float fields stacked in it.